# Extract formula from model in R

Tags: r, modeling

I'm building a function for many model types which needs to extract the formula used to make the model.  Is there a flexible way to do this?  For example:

```
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
z <- rnorm(10)
equation <- z ~ x + y
model <- lm(equation)
```

I what I need to do is extract the formula object "equation" once being passed the model.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could get what you wanted by:

```
  model$call
# lm(formula = formula)
```

And if you want to see what I did find out then use:

```
str(model)
```

Since you passed 'formula' (bad choice of names by the way) from the calling environment you might then need to extract from the object you passed:

```
 eval(model$call[[2]])
# z ~ x + y
```

@JPMac offered a more compact method: `formula(model)`. It's also worth looking at the mechanism used by the `formula.lm` function. The function named `formula` is generic and you use `methods(formula)` to see what S3 methods have been defined. Since the `formula.lm` method has an asterisk at its end, you need to wrap it in `getAnywhere:

```
> getAnywhere(formula.lm)
A single object matching ‘formula.lm’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for formula from namespace stats
  namespace:stats
with value

function (x, ...) 
{
    form <- x$formula
    if (!is.null(form)) {
        form <- formula(x$terms)
        environment(form) <- environment(x$formula)
        form
    }
    else formula(x$terms)
}
<bytecode: 0x36ff26158>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

So it is using "$" to extract the list item named "formula" rather than pulling it from the call. If the $formula item is missing (which it is in your case) then  It then replaces that with `formula(x$terms)` which I suspect is calling `formula.default` and looking at the operation of that function appears to only be adjusting the environment of the object.

Comment: Thanks for responding -- how do I actually access the formula object "formula".  If I try info <- model$call, info$formula just gives me a symbol object "formula".

Comment: I would suggest `as.list(model$call)$formula` rather than `model$call[[2]]`.

Comment: @mike: I'm not sure what you are asking. You are the one that decided to call your formula, "formula", and then passed that as a named argument to `lm`.  `fortunes::fortune("dog")` definitely applies here.

Comment: I'm late to the game...but I think you can do this: `formula(model)` to get the formula object that was passed to model.

Comment: That does look more direct indeed.

Comment: I recommend using `formula(model)` as suggested above. If one fits models using a function, then the call will not contain the actual formula used and one will get an error if one tries to use the formula found in the `$call` element.

Comment: `formula(model)` is the CORRECT answer. All the other answers are incorrect.

Comment: And interestingly you can pass ``lm(formula(model), data = data)`` directly instead of ``lm(formula = formula(model), data = data)``, though I'm not sure I'd recommend it. (I expected it to fail, as ``formula`` is precisely the name of the argument of ``lm()``)

Answer (score 6):

As noted, `model$call` will get you the call that created the `lm` object, but if that call contains an object itself as the model formula, you get the object name, not the formula.

The evaluated object, ie the formula itself, can be accessed in `model$terms` (along with a bunch of auxiliary information on how it was treated). This should work regardless of the details of the call to `lm`.